# Adding styling to LaTeX produced by MATLAB

Tags: include, matlab

MATLAB has a function called `publish` which has the option to export a script and its output as LaTeX.  It looks quite nice, although there are a few additional things that I would like to do to the output.  As I cannot figure out how to make MATLAB emit arbitrary LaTeX when it is publishing, the next best thing is to apply it after the fact.

MATLAB generates a complete file, ready to be fed to an interpreter.  It has `\documentclass{article}` headers and everything; it looks much like the following:

```
% This LaTeX was auto-generated from an M-file by MATLAB.
% To make changes, update the M-file and republish this document.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}

\sloppy
\definecolor{lightgray}{gray}{0.5}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\begin{document}

% generated code here

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to include this file from another file that defines my own formatting?

As a simple example, I would like to inject `\usepackage{fullpage}` into its output.

As a last resort, I'm willing to involve `sed` or similar, but that's almost as bad as hacking the MATLAB generator, which is a solution I've seen recommended elsewhere on the web.

Comment: *a solution I've seen recommended elsewhere on the web*. I'm curious, could you add a link?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I too was unimpressed by the style of the m-code typeset generated by MATLAB's `publish` function. I wanted `publish` to use, instead of a `verbatim` environment, an `lstlisting` environment in conjunction with one of the `listings` styles defined in my [`matlab-prettifier`](https://github.com/Jubobs/matlab-prettifier) package.

Therefore, as advised by Will in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197927/21891), I created my own stylesheet, called `matlab2latex_pretty.xsl`, on the basis of the default stylesheet that MATLAB uses. For information, on my Mac, the latter is located at `<matlab-installation-folder>/toolbox/matlab/codetools/private/mxdom2latex.xsl`.

My stylesheet, along with installation instructions, is available on GitHub: [Jubobs/pretty_publish](https://github.com/Jubobs/pretty_publish). You could have a look at it, as a starting point, to see how you can modify the native stylesheet to suit your needs.

---

As an example, here is a screenshot of the final product of

```
publish('peaks',...                                                       
    struct(...
    'format','latex',...
    'stylesheet','matlab2latex_pretty.xsl'...
))
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice, thanks!  This does seem like a good way to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot for providing the style file, it is very helpful. I've made an addition to it [on github](https://github.com/jubobs/pretty_publish/pull/1) that enables a TOC and multi-level headers. I hope it will prove useful to others.

Answer (score 4):

If by mean ‘hacking the MATLAB generator’ you mean copying their `.xsl` convertor and changing it for your application, I actually think that's the best approach in the long run with something in Matlab like:

```
publish(filename,...
  struct(...
  'format','latex',...
  'stylesheet','matlab2latex.xsl',...
  'evalCode',false...
  ));
```

E.g., for changing the `verbatim` environment to `lstlisting`.

When I looked at this once in the past (I'd like to work with someone to develop a more robust solution) I ended up stripping the output down to omit the preamble, etc., and simply `\input`-ing the generated LaTeX document in a ‘driver’ file. (This also had the advantage of being able to include multiple `.m` files into the one LaTeX document.)

An easier way of doing this is to load the `docmute` package; it allows you to `\input` a file such as generated LaTeX file from Matlab into another document. For example, you might write

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{full page}
\usepackage{docmute}
\begin{document}
\title{My Matlab document}
% publish the m-file first:
\input{html/mymatlab.tex}
\end{document}
```

(untested).

Comment: `docmute` looks like exactly what I'm looking for.  I'll give it a shot, thanks!  A better `publish` command would be better in the long run though.  I'll look into that too.

Comment: See my answer. One question: what version of MATLAB are you using? Mine (R2013a) doesn't allow the brace style you're using in your code. More specifically, it won't allow me to close braces right after a line break, even if preceded by a line-continuation token.

Comment: @Jukobs — good answer! Regarding brace style, I've been using this sort of form for years and it still seems to work in a trial version of 2014b I have installed. So I'm a bit confused. Note there's no comma before the final `...` ?

Comment: @WillRobertson ... you're right! If I don't use a comma before the `...` on the last line, no problem. I can't believe I had never tried that. Thanks for the tip! That said, I still don't find what the MATLAB syntax authorizes ideal. IMHO, it should really allow you to write that comma, so you can add more "key-value" lines after that without having to worry about adding that comma.

Comment: @Jubobs Definitely! I have a love/hate relationship with the Matlab programming language. Since I was thinking about this yesterday, I noticed that you *can* have a spurious comma for concatenating using square brackets `['x',...'y',...'z',...]` … which I don't understand.

Comment: @WillRobertson Yet another inconsistency. I'm with you on the love/hate relationship `:)` I'm currently gathering my thoughts for a blog post on "my beef with MATLAB"...

Comment: @WillRobertson If you haven't already, you should check out [Julia](http://julialang.org)! Its syntax is very similar to MATLAB's, but it's free and open-source, tends to be much faster, has nice built-in data structures (such as maps), a stronger type system, etc. IMO, a strong contender for MATLAB (in the long term).